# Checking single bits in a bitmask using std::pow

Tags: c++, bitmask

I have the following define to check an unsigned int bitmask for a certain bit.
Is there a more straightforward way (that doesn't include power of calculation) which I'm not aware of?

This is my [code](https://onlinegdb.com/r1X7v6c4r):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#define IS_BIT_SET(x) (foomask & (int)std::pow(2, x-1)) >> x-1 == 1 

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    unsigned int foomask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    if(IS_BIT_SET(1))
        cout << "Bit 1  is set" << endl;

    if(IS_BIT_SET(32))
        cout << "Bit 32  is set" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/test or for oldschool simulating a bitmask in an unsigned, typically you would use shifts (instead of pow) and bitwise and/or

Comment: `foomask & (1<<x)` should be enough. `1<<x` shift the first bit `x` times to the right position, and anding it with `foomask` will be non-0 or 0 depending if the correct bit is 1 or 0 - no need to shift again. If you want a proper true or false it is enough to compare to `> 0` without shifting.